# sencha touch 2 - local storage data not in view

Tags: sencha-touch-2, local-storage, sencha-architect

I'm making an webapp with sencha touch 2 (with Architet) and I have a problem with local storage: data isn't in the view.

If I check how "rows" has the storage It will return 4 (correct!), but on the view those records are not displayed.

Can you help me?

(Settings does not interact with products, therefore, ignore it!)

APP.JS:

```
Ext.application({
models: [
    'Products',
    'Settings'
],
stores: [
    'Settings',
    'Products'
],
views: [
    'Settings',
    'HomePage',
    'ProductsList'
],
controllers: [
    'Main'
],
name: 'YouPazzle',

launch: function() {

    Ext.create('YouPazzle.view.Settings', {fullscreen: true});
}});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
Ext.define('YouPazzle.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
},

launch: function() {
    var Settings = Ext.getStore('Settings');
    if(Settings.data.all.length === 0){
        console.log('Settagglio non eseguito');
    }else{
        console.log('Settagglio eseguito');
        this.goToHomePage();
    }
},

goToHomePage: function() {
    //Ext.Viewport.add(firststep);

    // Reverse the slide direction before using setActiveItem()

    var toPage = Ext.create('YouPazzle.view.HomePage');
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(toPage);

}
});
```

MODEL:

```
Ext.define('YouPazzle.model.Products', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'codice'
        },
        {
            name: 'obj'
        }
    ]
}});
```

STORAGE:

```
Ext.define('YouPazzle.store.Products', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'YouPazzle.model.Products'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'YouPazzle.model.Products',
    storeId: 'Products',
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage'
    }
}});
```

VIEW:

```
Ext.define('YouPazzle.view.ProductsList', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',

config: {
    itemId: 'productsList',
    store: 'Products',
    itemTpl: [
        '<div>Data View Item {codice}</div>'
    ],
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Prodotti',
            items: [

            ]
        }
    ]
}

initialize: function() {

}});
```

Answer (score 0):

change your view code

```
   itemTpl: '<div>Data View Item {codice}</div>',
```